# Guessing a word within 3 tries. If failed in 3rd try, continue to next statement

Tags: c#

So I need a solution that will let me guess a word from the jumbled letters. I must guess it within 3 tries. If I get it within the 3 tries, I will get 500 points. For every wrong guess I will get 250 points deduction. If I used up my 3 tries, the application will go on to the next word.

NOTes:

Before the break command, it continue to write the line "Answer? "
After the break command, same results

```
score = 1000; 
x = 0;

Console.WriteLine("WORD #1: ketbabasll");
Console.WriteLine("HINT: SPORTS");

do
{
    Console.Write("Answer? ");
    word = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
while (word != "basketball");

if (word == "basketball")
{
    score = score + 500;
}
else if (word != "basketball")
{
    score = score - 250;
    x = x + 1;

    if (x == 3)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try writing what this program is doing line-by-line and the error will be clear.

Comment: See what you do in your loop....

Answer (score 0):

Add a label to the code and add the label to the break eg:

```
do
{
    word = prompt("Answer? ");
}

while (word != "basketball");
myloop:
if (word == "basketball")
{
    score = score + 500;
}
else if (word != "basketball")
{
    score = score - 250;
    x = x + 1;

    if (x == 3)
    {
        break myloop;
    }
}
```